# Is it possible to use dot notation to query data from multiple tables in a DB in R?

Tags: sql, r

I can write simple queries in R using DBI like:

```
SELECT id, class, var3
FROM tableA
```

These queries work without a problem, but I'd like to write more complex queries that pull from multiple tables using dot notation such as:

```
SELECT a.id, a.class, b.id, b.rank
FROM tableA AS a, tableB AS b
WHERE a.id=b.id
```

When I do the second one in R I get an error saying that the SQL command was not properly ended. Does anyone know a way to accomplish this?

Comment: That looks like an *implicit join*, which is (afaik) not supported by all DBMSes. You might be able to do an explicit join with something like `select a.id,... from tableA as a left join tableB as b on a.id=b.id`.

Comment: But said differently, since you're using `DBI`, this suggests that your problem has nothing to do with R and more to do with the specific DBMS you are using. If my comment above doesn't help, you will likely need to include more information (such as DBMS, server software version, DBI version, etc).

Comment: You were right @r2evans, there were 2 problems: 1) the implicit joins, 2) the keyword "AS". Thank you!